# Identity relative to different orthonormal bases is unitary

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional inner product space, and let $\beta,\beta'$ both be orthonormal bases for $V$.
Is it the case that $[I]^{\beta'}_{\beta}$ is unitary? If so, how can we prove this?

Note: A unitary matrix is an invertible matrix whose inverse equals its conjugate transpose. A unitary operator is one that preserves inner products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say $\beta=\{v_1,\dotsc,v_n\}$ and $\beta^\prime=\{v_1^\prime,\dotsc,v_n^\prime\}$. A standard theorem for orthonormal bases implies that
\begin{array}{rcrcrcrcrcrcrc}
v_1 & = & \langle v_1,v_1^\prime\rangle v_1^\prime & + & \dotsb & + & \langle v_1,v_n^\prime\rangle v_n^\prime \\
v_2 & = & \langle v_2,v_1^\prime\rangle v_1^\prime & + & \dotsb & + & \langle v_2,v_n^\prime\rangle v_n^\prime \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &&\ddots & &\vdots \\
v_n & = & \langle v_n,v_1^\prime\rangle v_1^\prime & + & \dotsb & + & \langle v_n,v_n^\prime\rangle v_n^\prime \\
\end{array}
This implies that
$$
P=[I]_\beta^{\beta^\prime}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\langle v_1,v_1^\prime\rangle &\dotsb &\langle v_n,v_1^\prime\rangle \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\langle v_1,v_n^\prime\rangle & \dotsb & \langle v_n,v_n^\prime\rangle
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Similarly, we have
$$
[I]_{\beta^\prime}^{\beta}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\langle v_1^\prime,v_1\rangle &\dotsb &\langle v_n^\prime,v_1\rangle \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\langle v_1^\prime,v_n\rangle & \dotsb & \langle v_n^\prime,v_n\rangle
\end{bmatrix}
$$
But we also have $P^{-1}=[I]_{\beta^\prime}^{\beta}$ (why?). Hence
$$
P^{-1}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\langle v_1^\prime,v_1\rangle &\dotsb &\langle v_n^\prime,v_1\rangle \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\langle v_1^\prime,v_n\rangle & \dotsb & \langle v_n^\prime,v_n\rangle
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\overline{\langle v_1,v_1^\prime\rangle} &\dotsb &
\overline{\langle v_n,v_1^\prime\rangle} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\overline{\langle v_1,v_n^\prime}\rangle & \dotsb & \overline{\langle v_n,v_n^\prime\rangle}
\end{bmatrix}^\top
=P^*
$$
This proves that $P$ is unitary.